# Failing to install omentpp 4.1

Tags: compiler-errors, omnet++

I am trying to install omnetpp 4.1 (can't install the new version). Anyway, running `./configure` reports no errors or warnings, but when I run `make` I get the following:

```
make MODE=release
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1'
***** Configuration: MODE=release, TOOLCHAIN_NAME=gcc, LIB_SUFFIX=.so ****
===== Checking environment =====
mkdir -p /home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1/bin
===== Compiling utils ====
cd /home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1/src/utils && make
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1/src/utils'
g++ abspath.cc -o /home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1/out/gcc-release/src/utils/abspath
abspath.cc: In function ‘std::string toAbsolutePath(const char*)’:
abspath.cc:62:38: error: ‘getcwd’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [/home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1/out/gcc-release/src/utils/abspath] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1/src/utils'
make[1]: *** [utils] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yotam/omnetpp-4.1'
make: *** [allmodes] Error 2
```

I am running ununtu 12.10 if it matters. Seems to be code errors, right?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit the file `src/utils/abspath.cc` and manually add the following:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Save and compile again. Problem solved.